# EventGrid-triggered, Python Azure Function keeps triggering after successfully running?

Tags: python, triggers, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, retry-logic

There are a couple other topics out there, but none with solutions or none pertaining to Python Functions.

**Background:**

- EventGrid-triggered, Python Azure Function
- EventGrid messages created **only** when a blob is uploaded to a given Storage Account
- Function receives message, downloads blob from message URL and does "stuff"
- Function can run for several seconds/minutes (up to 120 seconds for large blobs)

**Example of issue:**

- 4 files uploaded to blob container in correct Storage Account
- Function successfully triggered 4 times, by 4 separate EventGrid messages
- Function downloads blob from URL in each message, does "stuff"
- ~55 seconds later, 4 more EventGrid messages trigger the Function all over again (for the same 4 files!)
- Everything repeats

**This happens multiple times resulting in 12 Function executions for 4 files:**

- And corresponding **output** from the "stuff" the Function does!

[image]

It gets ridiculous when 2500 files are uploaded to the Storage Account!

Seems like I need to adjust the EventGrid retry timing. But I don't see a setting for this in the Portal:

[image]

**How do I prevent this behavior?**

**EDIT 1:** Then today... no issue with 16 files uploaded... why is this Function inconsistently being triggered by EventGrid?

[image]

**EDIT 2:** And again today... for no reason, ~an hour later... EventGrid fired off a bunch more triggers though NO MORE FILES have been uploaded to the storage account.

[image]

**Here are the EventGrid stats for 16 files being uploaded to storage account.**

- You can clearly see the numbers are all over the place with in some cases, ~1hour between retries.
- Looks quite arbitrary to me

[image]

**EDIT 3:** For anyone interested...

- What appears to be happening is: EventGrid is being triggered by **TWO** events within the Storage Account for a **SINGLE** file upload.
- This is generating two EventGrid schemas (one for a ["Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated event"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#microsoftstorageblobcreated-event) and one for ["Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated event (Data Lake Storage Gen2)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#microsoftstorageblobcreated-event-data-lake-storage-gen2)
- Because the `data.url` parameter of the EventGrid message is different (`xxx.blob.core.windows.net` vs. `xxx.dfs.core.windows.net`), my Function is failing (as it uses [`BlobClient.from_blob_url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#from-blob-url-blob-url--credential-none--snapshot-none----kwargs-)
- More to come.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule-and-duration), the subscriber (such as your EventGridTrigger function) needs to send a response back to the AEG within the **30 seconds** otherwise the message is queued for retry.

Note, that the event is removed from the retry queue when the AEG received within 3 minutes successful respond from the delivery destination endpoint (subscriber). If the deadlettering feature is on, the event is removed from the retry queue also when the respond failure code are 400 or 413.

Based on the above and your long running subscriber, the AEG sent a duplicate event within the 3 minutes.

I do recommend use a *Push-Pull* pattern in your solution such as delivery an event to the storage queue.

Comment: What do you mean by "Push-Pull" pattern? Could you point me to an example?

Comment: Notice in the logs above... the Function in this case is running from ~1sec to 4.5secs. This is WELL WITHIN the 30sec retry window.

Comment: Then today, each Function run is ~1 - 3.5secs. This time WITH NO RETRIES occurring? Is EventGrid a production-ready trigger for Azure Functions that run less than 30secs?

Comment: The delivery *Push-Pull* pattern in the loosely decupled Pub/Sub model allows to deliver (store) events to the resource entity (such as storage queue, event hub, service bus, etc.) in the real-time and than pulled up their based on the needs. Note, that the AEG requires to receive a response (ACK/NACK) from the delivery process based on the delivery and retry policy. One more note, in the *Push-Push* pattern (such as EventGridTrigger) the response time can be depended also when the function "cold started"

Comment: For test purposes: turn on a deadlettering feature with "maxDeliveryAttempts":1,"eventTimeToLiveInMinutes":30 for details about the *lastDeliveryOutcome*

Comment: RE: Cold start: I'm using Premium App Service Plan (P2V2). From what I understand, there is no cold start for this level of plan.

Comment: RE: Deadlettering, maxDelivAttempts, eventTTL: Will test this after support call with MS. I don't want to alter any variables at the moment.

Comment: @ericOnline, I’m facing the same issue. Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes I did! I had to add an advanced filter to the EventGrid trigger: `data.api` `String contains` `FlushWithClose`. See the `Note` here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#list-of-the-events-for-azure-data-lake-storage-gen-2-rest-apis

Comment: @ericOnline how adding filter solved this issue ? Does it improve event grid trigger function ACK to AEG ?

Comment: @Pintu, before the advanced filter was in place, EventGrid would trigger for each API call of the file upload. In my case, when Azure Data Factory uploads a file, it uses the `AppendFile` api for each chunk of the file. This triggered EventGrid and the Function each time. Instead, I filtered EG to only trigger when the `FlushWithClose` api is used. This is the last api called by ADF when has finished a file upload.